# Annotation Button Not Displaying

Tags: ios, mapkit

Im working with Mapkit for the first time and i am having a problem of Annotation Button not displaying.

I am using xCode 5 and iOS7. I also did try in xCode 4.6 iOS 6.1 and that did not work either.

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MKAnnotation.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate> {
IBOutlet UITextField *name;
MKMapView *mapView;
CLLocationManager *locationManager;
NSString *dateString;
NSString *nameString;
//MKPinAnnotationView *pinView;
NSString *pinID;

}

@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
@property(nonatomic, retain) UITextField *name;

-(IBAction)addPin;
-(IBAction)addName;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "PinDrop.h"
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MKAnnotation.h>

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize mapView;
@dynamic name;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
name.delegate = self;
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;

[mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
[mapView setZoomEnabled:YES];
[mapView setScrollEnabled:YES];
//Get Location
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; // whenever we move
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
NSLog(@"%@", [self deviceLocation]);

//Make Pin
MKCoordinateRegion region = { { 0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0 } };
region.center.latitude = locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude;
region.center.longitude = locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude;
region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.005f;
region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.005f;
[mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(IBAction)addPin {
[self getDateTime];
//Get Location
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; // whenever we move
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
NSLog(@"%@", [self deviceLocation]);

//Make Pin
MKCoordinateRegion region = { { 0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0 } };
region.center.latitude = locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude;
region.center.longitude = locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude;
region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.005f;
region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.005f;
[mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];


//Pin Info
PinDrop *ann = [[PinDrop alloc] init];
nameString = name.text;
NSLog(@"Name: %@", nameString);
ann.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Title: %@", nameString];
ann.subtitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Date: %@", dateString];
ann.coordinate = region.center;
[mapView addAnnotation:ann];

//Clear name and stuff
name.text = @"";

}
- (NSString *)deviceLocation {
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"latitude: %f longitude: %f", locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude, locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];
}

-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mV viewForAnnotation:
(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = nil;
if(annotation != mapView.userLocation)
{
    static NSString *defaultPinID = @"com.invasivecode.pin";
    pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultPinID];
    if ( pinView == nil ) pinView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]
                                      initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:defaultPinID] autorelease];

    pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
    pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
    pinView.animatesDrop = YES;
}
else {
    [mapView.userLocation setTitle:@"I am here"];
    NSLog(@"Was Else");
}
return pinView;
}
- (void)dealloc
{
[mapView release];
[super dealloc];
}
@end
```

PinDrop.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MKAnnotation.h>

@interface PinDrop : NSObject <MKAnnotation> {

CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
NSString *title;
NSString *subtitle;

}

@property(nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *subtitle;

@end
```

PinDrop.m

```
#import "PinDrop.h"

@implementation PinDrop
@synthesize coordinate, title, subtitle;


@end
```

Comment: When you say no "annotation button", do you mean that your annotation view (the pin) never shows up? Can you confirm which of your `NSLog` statements you're seeing and which you are not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of thoughts:

1. When starting location services, you should

   - specify the delegate of `self`; and
   - the view controller should implement the [`CLLocationManagerDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html) call, [`didUpdateLocations`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007124-CH3-SW16)

   You can't just start location services and then expect to immediately have the location. You really need to wait for location services to call its `delegate`. In fact, be forewarned that the location services on a physical device actually takes a couple of iterations with increasing accuracy (i.e. smaller `horizontalAccuracy` values) each time.
2. In  your `addPin`, your instantiating a new location manager object. (You're also not releasing the prior one, BTW.) You should just use the instance that you created in `viewDidLoad`, not instantiate a new one.
3. Is your `viewForAnnotation` getting called? I hope that you specified the view controller as the map's `delegate` in Interface Builder.
4. It looks like you have some class properties that you're not releasing in `dealloc` (e.g. the location manager). I'd run this code through the static analyzer ("Analyze" on the "Product" menu), and correct anything it warns you about.